# What is it asking when it says define and then gives a function and some conditions?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, terminology

For example, the question:
Define $f$ on $[3,4]$ by $f(x)=x+5$. Using the definition of the Riemann integral, show that $f$ is integrable on $[3,4]$.

or
Let $E=\{x \in \mathbb{R} : x \ge 1\}$. Define $f_n(x)= \frac{nx}{1+nx}$. Find lim and so on...

I understand what the second part of the questions are asking. But when it says define what should I be doing, what does it mean?

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: It's not telling you to do anything, it's telling you "Let $f$ be defined by... Then show that it is Riemann integrable".

Comment: It doesn't tell you to do anything, it just means we are defining a function $f$ with domain (in your first example) $[3,4]$, which sends $x\in[3,4]$ to $x+5$. Incidentally, the range should also be specified.

Comment: Perhaps this will help? It's like saying: "Let the person in Central City be Elis Roland Weeks. Show that this person is less than 1.75 meters in height."

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, it's just another way of saying "Let the function $f$ be defined in this manner...", and then it asks you to prove some property about it.

It's in the same kind of imperative as appears in "Suppose $x \in [0, 1]$. Show that $x$ is positive."

Comment: I meant to write this as a community answer, but there's no option for that in mobile, so if anyone can change that, it would be nice.